# What does $[n=1]$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Studying recurrence relations I stumbled upon this expression in a solution to the problem of finding a closed formula to this:

$a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2}; a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$

To start the solution, the person made the relation valid to all $n$, introducing the strange term:

$a_n = 5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} + [n = 1]$

What does $[n=1]$ mean? Does it add one in the case that $n = 1$?

Comment: Seems like [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Comment: That should be it, thank you. If you want post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) and works exactly the way you deduced:
$$[n = 1] = 
\begin{cases}
1, \text{ if } n=1\\
0, \text{ if } n \neq 1
\end{cases}$$